Couchbase Rebalance Failed because of eventing failure
I am getting the below error when rebalancing a Couchbase cluster with 2 nodes after removing 1 node. Now it’s not even allowing me to add back the node and it has been pending for a very long time.
Service ‘eventing’ exited with status 1. Restarting. Messages: [goport(/opt/couchbase/bin/eventing-producer)] 2024/06/27 18:51:03 failed to start child: fork/exec /opt/couchbase/bin/eventing-producer: no such file or directory

The file "/opt/couchbase/bin/eventing-producer" doesn't exist on the server. The node in question is now unavailable to use as its rebalance is incomplete.
Is it possible to remove the eventing service from a node?
Your help is appreciated.
